# How do I show hidden files beginning with a certain letter in Linux?

Tags: linux, ls

I'm trying to show hidden files that begin with the letter `b`.

I have tried:

```
ls b
ls b*
```

and many other options but can't find a solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command you need to use is:

```
ls .b*
```

Hidden files start with a `.` in Linux.

The way to make a file hidden is to rename it prefixing a `.` character to its name.

Most configuration files start with a `.` character like `.vimrc` and `.bashrc`, meaning they are there just to be used by the specific application, and normal users are not meant to see it because they may accidentally alter it and cause misconfiguration.

Comment: It should be: ls .b*

Comment: Welcome. (2) I know, mistype, edited :)